# Why is pagination in wordpress not working?

Tags: wordpress, pagination, posts

It was previously working but now for some reasons the button "2" and "next page" seem not working anymore.
Any help?

[image]

These are only settings i touched.

[image]

Comment: What do you mean by "not working?"

Comment: When i click on "next" or "2" the page just reloads. Even if i manually add /2 in the link i do not get back the page number 2. Though i know it exists. Infact, if i increse the number of post per page i am able to see the other posts that are supposed to be shown when i click on "next"

Comment: Any idea why this is not working? Many thanks

Comment: I'd recommend reaching out to Elementor's support, since it appears you're using their plugin.